# How to add client certificate in ASP.NET Web API in-memory testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, testing, asp.net-web-api

I want to test my Web API service using in-memory `HttpServer`.

The current setup looks the following:

```
 var httpConfig = CreateTestHttpConfiguration();
 var server = new HttpServer(httpConfig);

 var handler = new WebRequestHandler();
 var cert = new X509Certificate2("filename", "password");
 handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
 var client = HttpClientFactory.Create(handler, server);
```

I can make requests to the server using these `client` and everything works except that certificate is not added to the request.

As I understand that happens since `server` executes before `handler` (I can't rearrange them since they implement different interfaces) and since `server` immediately responses `handler` is not even executed (I've tested this assumption using `HttpClientHandler` subclass instead of `handler`).

So my question is: **How can I add the client certificate for in-memory testing?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach will do it:

```
        var server = new HttpServer(configuration);
        var invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(server);
        var certificate = GetCertificate();

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost/YourPath");
        request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.ClientCertificateKey] = certificate;
        var result = await invoker.SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None);
```